# Add an exception to ExpressJS app.use()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, server

I'm working on a NodeJS project, and using Express as my routing framework.

I have a register form in my site, and a login form, both of which send requests to `/users` (`/register` and `/login` respectively). However, I would like to be able to have `/users/:userID` as routes to see profiles of different users, but of course, this routes imply that I have a session_id for every logged in user.

My question is, how can I use `app.use('/users', checkForSessionId)`, without applying it to register and login?

Comment: I think a good way to do this is turning your `checkForSessionId` function into middleware, and having the `/users/` Router contain the `/login`, `/signup`, `/:userId` routes. This way, you can only put the checkForSessionId middleware only on the routes you want, while keeping them separate. [middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where you need to use middleware

app.js

```
var users = require('./routes/user');
app.use('/users', users);
```

./routes/user.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
function checkForSessionId(req, res, next){
    //if no valid session
    //    return res.status(401).json("not authorised");
    //else
    next();
}

router.get('/:userId', checkForSessionId, function(req, res){
    //this is a route which requires authentication
})

router.post('/register', function(req, res){
    //authentication is not necessary
})

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Ok, so that means that if I have 20 routes needing auth I will have to add the middleware in everyone of them :( thanks a lot! It solves my problem!

Comment: It depends on how your resource hierarchy is. You can also use middleware for an entire resource instead of adding middleware for each and every route.